# MySQL merge arrays from multiple JSON rows

Tags: mysql, arrays, merge, mysql-json

I have a table with a json column that looks like this :

```
+----+------------+
| id | myfield    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | ["1", "2"] |
|  2 | ["3", "2"] |
|  3 | ["2", "4"] |
+----+------------+
```

How can I merge all values from *myfield* in one array?

I need a result that will look like this: `["1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4"]`, or even better with removed duplicates.

I tried using this query:
`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(myfield) FROM json_test` but as a result I'm getting:

`[["1", "2"], ["3", "2"], ["2", "4"]]`

I assume I need a query in combination with the function JSON_MERGE.

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return? The best answer could depend on which exact version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: @BillKarwin 5.7.22, but I'm open to upgrading to any needed version as I'm at the project's beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution but it requires MySQL 8.0 for the [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(j.myvalue) AS flattened_values
FROM mytable, JSON_TABLE(
  mytable.myfield, '$[*]' COLUMNS(myvalue INT PATH '$')
) AS j;
```

Output:

```
+------------------+
| flattened_values |
+------------------+
| 1,2,3,2,2,4      |
+------------------+
```

I would actually recommend avoiding storing JSON arrays. Instead, store multi-valued data in a normalized manner, in a second table. Then you could just use GROUP_CONCAT() on the joined table.

I have still yet to hear of a use of JSON in MySQL that isn't better accomplished by using database normalization.

Comment: I expected a simpler solution since MySQL officially supports JSON operations, but anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is MySQL's solution for JSON operations. All use of JSON is done through a variety of [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html), which are still evolving. This makes an old-school normalized database seem pretty good doesn't it?